# What does Subscription add function do with Promise's resolve call-back

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I can see in GitHub project `angular-10-signup-verification-boilerplate` the following snippet:

```
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
        accountService.refreshToken()
            .subscribe()
            .add(resolve);
    });
}
```

I was wondering if somebody could explain what is the meaning of `add` function with parameter `resolve`. Documentation says that `add` function is for adding additional subscribers so they can be unsubscribed in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add` method of the [subscription](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription#add) returned from `subscribe` will run when the subscription completes (and is subsequently unsubscribed)

In your example the `resolve` will be called when the `refreshToken` completes. When the Promise resolves and the APP_INITIALIZER (which is waiting for the promise to resolve) will continue

Note: I've never seen it used before - the more common approach is to use the subscribe next/error/complete functions or a `finalize` operator

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I am still missing is -the parameter to `add` method is of type `TeardownLogic` but it is being passed `resolve' call-back method from Promise, Isn't there type clash or I am not understanding it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this by code:                                                                                                 `const numbers: Observable<number> = interval(1000);
  const takeFourNumbers = numbers.pipe(take(4));
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
    takeFourNumbers.subscribe()
      .add(resolve);
  }); `                                                                                                                                                   But `resolve` in `add` displays an error.

Comment: Didn't work. But if I define `Promise` with the void type like this: `new Promise<void>` - it works.

Comment: Drenai BTW. Is unsubscribe called automatically (when subscription finishes) or I need to call it somewhere?

Comment: One last question. `add` method accepts `resolve` method. However doc says that it should be a Subscription to be unsubscribed later on by framework. So how RxJs handles the call to resolve method when it expects Subscription? I am not sure if my question is clear.